# Knit Document Results in Error in seq.int

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr

When knitting my document, the following code halts knitting and results in an error. Of note, in normal operation this code works by displaying the required graph. This problem only occurs when knitting the document.

I attempted to insert echo=false hoping to just bypass the problem, but ended up with the same error message.

The Code:

```
qplot(wt, mpg, data=mtcars, colour=factor(am)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(ymin = lcl, ymax = ucl), data=grid, stat="identity") +
  ggtitle("MPG, Weight, & Transmission Relationship")
```

The Error:

```
Quitting from lines 131-134 (MotorTrend.Rmd) 
Error in seq.int(U[1L], U[2L], length.out = nx + 1) : 
  'length.out' must be a non-negative number
Calls: <Anonymous> ... lapply -> FUN -> <Anonymous> -> f -> <Anonymous> -> f

Execution halted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to better define my terms, so I added additional code:

```
model <- lm(mpg ~ wt + factor(am) + wt*factor(am), data=mtcars)
grid <- with(mtcars, expand.grid(
  wt = seq(min(wt), max(wt), length = 20),
  am = levels(factor(am))))
grid$mpg <- stats::predict(model, newdata=grid)

err <- stats::predict(model, newdata=grid, se = TRUE)
grid$ucl <- err$fit + 1.96 * err$se.fit
grid$lcl <- err$fit - 1.96 * err$se.fit
qplot(wt, mpg, data=mtcars, colour=factor(am)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(ymin = lcl, ymax = ucl), data=grid, stat="identity") +
  ggtitle("MPG, Weight, & Transmission Relationship")
```